# Dynamic Add Delete of Partial View with Dropdownlist MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Hi All I'm trying to create a view with Add and Delete buttons for rows in which a row is a partial view. Here's what I have so far.

Main View

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Add Associated Assessments</legend>
    <div id="divPartial"></div>
    <input type="button" id="addassessment" name="addassessment" value="Add Assessment" />
    <br />

    @section Scripts
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#addassessment').on('click', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    url: '/PositionAssessments/AddNewAssessment'
                }).success(function (partialView) {
                    $('#divPartial').append(partialView);
                });
            });

            $("#deleteRow").on("click", function () {
                $(this).parents("#assessmentRow:first").remove();
                return false;
            });
        </script>
    }
</fieldset>
```

Partial View

```
@model MyApp.Models.AssessmentAddView
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Assessments"))
{
    <div id="assessmentRow" class="assessmentRow">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, Model.Data, "Select Assessment", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "display: inline" })
        <input type="button" id="deleteRow" name="deleteRow" value="Delete Row" />
    </div>
}
```

AssessmentAddView Class

```
public class AssessmentAddView
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Data { get; set; }
    public string SelectedId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult AddNewAssessment()
{
    return PartialView("_Assessment");//return your partial view here
}

public ActionResult _Assessment()
{
    var model = new AssessmentAddView
    {
        Data = ViewBag.AssessmentList = new SelectList(db.tblAssessment.OrderBy(a => a.AssessmentName), "Id", "AssessmentName")
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Ok when I click Add Assessment I get an Internal Error (500) but if I take out the Drop down and put some basic text in, it works.

If I leave it as basic text and the add works, the delete button does not work without any error.

If I go to the partial view itself, it loads fine with a dropdown and all the assessments in.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can not see the delete function for onclick="deleteFunction()". That is a possible error?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I've updated the code to reflect the removal. The delete button does nothing now without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i've now solved it. Thanks to Stephen Muecke for your help (not sure where you original answer has gone as I would have accepted it). So as mentioned I wasn't passing the model to the partial view in my controller so was getting a 500 error. With the Delete row I've connected it to the controller so it deletes current assessments off the database. Also I was having a problem deleting newly created views (no database id) which was solved by adding the delete script in my partial view.

For others wanting to have dropdowns in their partial view here is my code.

Main View

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.AssessmentAddView>
<fieldset>
                <legend>Add Associated Assessments</legend>

                <div id="divPartial">
                    @foreach (var mod in Model)
                    {

                        @Html.Partial("_Assessment", mod)
                    }
                </div>

                <input type="button" id="addassessment" name="addassessment" value="Add Assessment" />
                <br />


                @section Scripts
                {
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $('#addassessment').on('click', function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                async: false,
                                url: '/MyController/AddNewAssessment'
                            }).success(function (partialView) {
                                $('#divPartial').append(partialView);
                            });
                        });

                        $('.delete').click(function () {
                            var container = $(this).closest('.assessmentRow');
                            var id = container.find('.Id').val();
                            if (id) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    async: false,
                                    url: '/MyController/DeleteAssessment',
                                    data: { Id: id }
                                }).success(function (result) {
                                    container.remove();
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                // New Add so without id
                                container.remove();
                            }
                        });
                    </script>
                }
            </fieldset>
```

Partial View

```
@model MyApp.Models.AssessmentAddView
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
                    $('.delete').on('click', function () {
                        var container = $(this).closest('.assessmentRow');
                            container.remove();
                    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Assessments"))
{
    <div class="assessmentRow">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id, new { @class = "Id" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, Model.Data, "Select Assessment", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "display: inline" })
        <button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
}
```

AssessmentAddView Class

```
public class PositionAssessmentView
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Data { get; set; }

        public string SelectedId { get; set; }
    }
```

MyController

```
public ActionResult Edit(string StaffID)
{
var query = from s in db.tblStaffAssessment
                        where (s.StaffID.Equals(StaffID))
                        select s;

            var currentAssessments = new List<AssessmentAddView>();

            foreach (var s in query)
            {

                currentAssessments.Add(new AssessmentAddView()
                {
                    Id = s.Id,
                    Data = new SelectList(db.tblAssessment.OrderBy(a => a.AssessmentName), "Id", "AssessmentName"),
                    SelectedId = s.AssessmentID
            });
            }

            return View(currentAssessments);
}    

public ActionResult Edit(IEnumerable<AssessmentAddView> assessments)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (AssessmentAddView item in assessments)
                {
                    //perform edit action
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyController");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyController");
        }

public ActionResult AddNewAssessment()
            {
                var model = new AssessmentAddView
                {
                    Data = new SelectList(db.tblAssessment.OrderBy(a => a.AssessmentName), "Id", "AssessmentName")
                };
                return PartialView("_Assessment", model);//return your partial view here
            }

public ActionResult DeleteAssessment(string Id)
            {
                // do delete action with id
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyController");
            }
```